# in UE5 How do I write shader keywords for me to toggle on and off on the c++ side in UE like Unity, e.g. Material.EnableKeyword(“NORMAL_MAP”);

Tags: unreal

I’m writing a custom shader node. How do I write shader keywords for me to toggle on and off on the c++ side in UE5 like Unity, e.g. Material.EnableKeyword(“NORMAL_MAP”);